# Why calling `free(malloc(8))`?

Tags: c, objective-c, malloc

[The Objective-C runtime's `hashtable2.mm` file](https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/hashtable2.mm.auto.html) contains the following code:

```objectivec
static void bootstrap (void) {
    free(malloc(8));
    prototypes = ALLOCTABLE (DEFAULT_ZONE);
    prototypes->prototype = &protoPrototype; 
    prototypes->count = 1;
    prototypes->nbBuckets = 1; /* has to be 1 so that the right bucket is 0 */
    prototypes->buckets = ALLOCBUCKETS(DEFAULT_ZONE, 1);
    prototypes->info = NULL;
    ((HashBucket *) prototypes->buckets)[0].count = 1;
    ((HashBucket *) prototypes->buckets)[0].elements.one = &protoPrototype;
};
```

Why does it allocate and release the 8-bytes space immediately?

Another source of confusion is [this method from `objc-os.h`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/objc-os.h.auto.html):

```objectivec
static __inline void *malloc_zone_malloc(malloc_zone_t z, size_t size) { return malloc(size); }
```

While it uses only one parameter, does the signature ask for two?

Comment: Perhaps there is no allocation table before `malloc()` is called.

Comment: I which project found you that code?

Comment: Regarding Q2: Probably the interface is designed to support zones but your current implementation does not provide them. Yet, the API is still the same and you must provide a function with the defined signature because everyone who uses that function will provide 2 parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question I can only assume. My bet it was done to avoid/reduce memory churn, or segment the memory for some other reason. You can briefly find where it's discussed in [the Changelog of `bmalloc`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/bmalloc/bmalloc-7606.2.104.1.1/ChangeLog) (which is not quite relevant, but i could not find a better reference):

> 2017-06-02  Geoffrey Garen  <ggaren@apple.com>
>
> ...
>
> Updated for new APIs. Note that we cache one free chunk per page
> class. This avoids churn in the large allocator when you
> `free(malloc(X))`

It's unclear however, if the memory churn is caused by this technique or it was supposed to address it.

For the second question, Objective-C runtime used to work with "zones" in order to destroy all allocated variables by just destroying the said zone, but it proved being error prone and later it was agreed to not use it anymore. The API, however still uses it [for historical reasons](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1571945-allocwithzone) (backward compatibility, i assume), but [says](https://web.archive.org/web/20160827072148/https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-193068) that zones are ignored:

> Zones are ignored on iOS and 64-bit runtime on OS X. You should not use zones in current development.